# React enzyme jest test cases are failing with antv g2plot

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, antv, g2plot

I'm using the React Enzyme Jest module to test my React app which contains the `antv/g2plot` module for charts. While I am using the module, the test case isn't running but after removing it, it's working perfectly fine. There is a problem with the model I think. Do you know any possible solution?

I'm trying to test the file which is using the `antv/g2plot` module for chart while testing. It's failing and giving a random error which is not relevant (the error variable not defined in my React app). If I try to run the test without this file it's running pretty well but with it it returns this error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the member of G2Plot dev-team. When you write unit test for chart with canvas, you should:

1. mock the canvas API, see https://github.com/hustcc/jest-canvas-mock
2. give the real document(include canvas) env, see https://github.com/hustcc/jest-electron

[G2Plot](https://github.com/antvis/G2Plot/blob/master/package.json#L110-L111) use jest-electron for unit test and debugger.